# How can I check a successful write on a binary file with c++?

Tags: c++, binary, binaryfiles, fstream

I have seen these two methods to check if a written was successful on a binary file:

```
if (!file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&variablle), sizeof(variable)))
{
    return false;
}
```

and

```
if(!file.good()) {
    cout << "Error occurred at writing time!" << endl;
    return false;
}
```

But, I'm not sure if this is ok, or in any case what is a good way to check that?

Comment: write is an async operation. Data is copied in memory and scheduled for write to disk, so it is unknown at write time whether the disk write will succeed.

Comment: This part is suspicious: `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&variable), sizeof(variable)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Could you explain better why is suspicious?

Comment: Assuming variable is `std::uint32` or equivalent (i.e not a `std::uint8_t[N]`), then you indeed write variable, but with local endianess, making the serialization not portable. (if variable type has not even a fixed size as `int`, it is even worse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
if (!file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&variablle), sizeof(variable))) { return false; }
```

The result of the `write()` method returns a reference to the stream (file). You then apply the `operator !` to the file object, which returns a boolean value of `true` if `failbit` or `badbit` have been set on the object.

This line:

```
if(!file.good()) { cout << "Error occurred at writing time!" << endl; return false; }
```

Calls the method `good()` on the object `file` which returns a boolean value that is immediately not-ed with `!`. The result of the expression is true if any of the flags `failbit`, `badbit` or `eofbit` are set.

---

So there is a slight difference in behaviour, as the first version does not check `eofbit`. But effectively they are doing the same thing.

---

To address some of the comments.

This means you have successfully written to the c++ stream object. At this point it may or may not have been flushed to a physical disk as there is buffering between the write() call and disk.

You could potentially use the `flush()` to make sure data has been synchronized with the output sequence.

Most applications don't bother to go to this level of checking (but it will depend on the application).

---

Summary:

It is usually sufficient to check that `write()` has succeeded by using the first version.

```
 if (!file.write(/* Stuff */)) {
     // the write failed.
     // Do something that indicates failure.
 }
```

If you want to inform the user about successes/failure you usually don't do that at every write operation. I would do a check at the end (when all writing has been completed).

```
 if (!file.good()) {
     // Tell the user something went wrong.
 }
```